# Autocomplete for instance variables

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I tried to find the answer to this (seemly simple) problem, but cannot. I am trying to have Pycharm show me code completion for instance variables. Type hinting seems to only work in the same function. I also tried defining the type in the docstrings, but that still does not work. How can I get Pycharm to show me autocomplete suggestions for instance variables?

```
class Girl:
    gender = "female"

    def __init__(self, name:str):
        self.name = name
        self.name.capitalize()      # <- Pycharm shows me capitalize() as a method of name:str

    def capitalize_name(self):
        """
        :cvar name:str              # <-
        :type name:str              # <--- These don't
        :cvar self.name:str         # <--- help either
        :type self.name:str         # <-
        """
        self.name = self.name.....  # <- Pycharm does not know the type of self.name


alice = Girl(name="Alice")
alice.capitalize_name()
```

Comment: `self.name` is not a class variable

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry, I was also looking to defining class variables as None and then updating them in the init method and confused the terminology. Thanks

Comment: The problem is in reassignment. Completion works if `self.name = self.name....` replaced with `print(self.name....)`. Please fill an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from 2012, is there any better support now?

```
def capitalize_name(self):
    assert isinstance(self.name, str)
    self.name = self.name....   # <- works now
```

Ref: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205807049-How-to-improve-PyCharm-code-completion-auto-complete-